# Unable to Parse date with ParseExact()

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a code to parse a logfile within a specific date range, logfile content is below:

For eg: extracting the date (11/28 07:08:46) and parsing it.

```
[C79C] ComputerName:BETHGARWICK UserID:A0006 Beth Garwick Station 9  LanId: | (11/28 07:08:46) | Client is disconnected from agent.
[C79C] ComputerName:BETHGARWICK UserID: Logged out Station 0 LanId: | (11/28 07:08:51) | Client is connected to agent.

[EB7C] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 4  LanId: | (11/28 07:12:08) | Client is disconnected from agent.
[EB7C] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 4  LanId: | (11/28 07:12:13) | Client is connected to agent.

[EC44] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900  LanId: | (11/28 07:55:08 - 11/28 07:55:18) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [74.125.224.82] 3 times
[EC44] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900  LanId: | (11/28 07:55:23) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [www.google.com]
[EC44] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900  LanId: | (11/28 07:55:29 - 11/28 07:55:49) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [74.125.224.50] 5x

[EC44] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900  LanId: | (11/28 07:55:54 - 11/28 07:56:45) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [74.125.224.50] 11 times
[EC44] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900  LanId: | (11/28 07:56:50) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [www.google.com]
```

Tried .net functions parseexact(), parse() but did not work.

```
$patter = 'mm/dd'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$logfiles = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Temp\HTTPS\QoS_logs\test.logs"

$logfiles | foreach {

$dateasText = $_.ToString().Split("|")[1].Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Trim()

$date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateasText,$pattern,$null)
```

> Exeption calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
>   At "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Temp\HTTPS\QoS_logs\test.logs:23 char:1
>   + $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateasText,$pattern,$null)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: You haven't even told us what the content of `$pattern` is, how can we possibly help?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just tried in C#, `DateTime.ParseExact("09/06", "MM/dd", null)` results in the 6th of September 2019

Comment: Untested: aren't you missing an n here: `$patter = 'mm/dd'`?

Comment: @ThomasSchremser oops, I had a typo when I tried that pattern: `"MM//dd"`.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser `mm` refers to minutes. You'd get `6/1/2019 12:09:00`

Comment: Your first code line should read `$pattern = 'MM/dd'` the n of pattern is missing and Month is upper case `MM`, the lower case `mm` is minutes. Aside from this your line extracting text fails on empty lines. Use a better RegEx to grep the date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos now the typo's on me ;-) I tried both variants and copied the wrong one.

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"_ means that your `$dateasText` string was not recognized as a valid DateTime (`"11/28 07:08:46"` doesn't match `"mm/dd"` pattern, it's `"MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$pattern` as a RegEx to grep the date in a capture group `dt`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\06\SO_57819852.ps1
$pattern = ' LanId: \| \((?<dt>[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])'

$logfile = "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Temp\HTTPS\QoS_logs\test.logs" # ".\test.logs"  # 

foreach($Line in Get-Content $logfile) {
    if ($Line -match $pattern){
        $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches.dt,'MM/dd HH:mm:ss',$null)
        $date
    }
}
```

Sample output in my German locale:

```
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:08:46
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:08:51
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:12:08
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:12:13
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:55:08
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:55:23
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:55:29
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:55:54
Donnerstag, 28. November 2019 07:56:50
```